# Creating Hector cluster in Java

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm trying to use a basic definition of Hector to create a Cassandra Cluster. This is my code (only the connection and schema part).

```
CassandraHostConfigurator chc = new CassandraHostConfigurator(
       "localhost");
    chc.setMaxActive(20);
    chc.setCassandraThriftSocketTimeout(3000);
    chc.setMaxWaitTimeWhenExhausted(4000);    
    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("mycluster", chc);
    System.out.println("cluster: " + cluster.getKnownPoolHosts(false));
    try{
        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDef = cluster.describeKeyspace("sensornetwork");
    } catch (HectorException he){
        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("sensornetwork",
                                                                     "ColumnFamilyName",
                                                                     ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);

        KeyspaceDefinition newKeyspace = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("sensornetwork",
                                                                   ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS,
                                                                   1,
                                                                   Arrays.asList(cfDef));    
        cluster.addKeyspace(newKeyspace, true);
   }


    // If keyspace does not exist, the CFs don't exist either. => create them.


    Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("sensornetwork", cluster);
```

I did this basically by following the Hector documentation on its own website.

The error I get is this one:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools
>   marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:401)
>     at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:232)
>     at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.addKeyspace(ThriftCluster.java:168)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.mavenpails2.SpeedLayer.CassandraPrepwork(SpeedLayer.java:62)

Clearly I'm creating a cluster without a working pool connection. I've changed the port and tried everything but can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely "localhost" wasnt listening for thrift. Will probably want to use a cql client like https://github.com/datastax/java-driver instead. Otherwise make sure you have thrift enabled in cassandra.yaml

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try Datastax then.